# Android: How to call Fragment class from activity using Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to call a Fragment class from Activity using Intent. Is it possible to implement. Please provide your views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fragment` needs to be hosted by a `FragmentActivity`, you can't add a fragment via an `Intent`.

You need to create a `FragmentManager` to add your fragment in the `FragmentActivity` (or call another `FragmentActivity` via an `Intent` and add your fragment on it).
See this topic for more information: [Add a Fragment to an Activity at Runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime).

Comment: Thanks Fllo. I'll try this as you have mentioned.

Comment: If change it to fragment activity fragment manager not working

Comment: Because you maybe need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead, @Eddie.

Answer (score 1):

```
            Fragment TargetFragment=new target_fragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content,TargetFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Only showing code can be confusing for some people.

Answer (score 0):

Intent can not be applicable to Activity to Fragment So there Is Another method

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new DashBoardFragment()).commit();
```