# How to run only one fragment on screen?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to run a single fragment from another fragment. I try:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lecturers_fragment,
            container, false);
    ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lecturersList);
    final List<Lecturer> allLecturersList = LecturerDatabaseHelper
            .getAllLecturers(getActivity());
    if (allLecturersList != null) {
        LecturerItemAdapter lecturerAdapter = new LecturerItemAdapter(
                mCurrentActivity, allLecturersList);
        list.setAdapter(lecturerAdapter);
    }
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int index, long id) {

            Lecturer lecturer = allLecturersList.get(index);
            L.i("Boulder name  is playing link it contains"
                    + lecturer.getName());

            Intent intent_lecturer = new Intent(mCurrentActivity,
                    LecturerFragment.class);
            intent_lecturer.putExtra(LecturerFragment.SELECTED_LECTURER,
                    lecturer);
            mCurrentActivity.startActivity(intent_lecturer);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

In my logcat i have this:

```
03-25 22:04:36.092: E/AndroidRuntime(12453): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.asi.sesjaapp.view.LecturerFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I already have answered to the question today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22637001/2668136 ^^

Comment: You can't write `new Intent(mCurrentActivity, LecturerFragment.class)` and then `mCurrentActivity.startActivity(intent_lecturer);` because the `LecturerFragment` class inherits from `Fragment`, not `Activity`.

Comment: Fllo but I run this from another fragment not activity.

Comment: @Json My mistake, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Intent intent_lecturer = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
            intent_lecturer.putExtra(LecturerFragment.SELECTED_LECTURER, lecturer);
            mCurrentActivity.startActivity(intent_lecturer);
```

You are in a fragment, instead of mCurrentActivity just give your parent activity, something like this:

```
new Intent(getActivity() , LecturerFragment.class);
```

and again it looks like LecturerFragment.class is a fragment it should be an activity.

Note: Make sure your parent activity extends FragmentActivity

If this answer didn't help you please post your Parent Activity code and fragments code.

Comment: I try to use your code. I when I click nothing happens. FragmentActivity is the parent fragment or a fragment of which it calls LecturerFragment?

Comment: your parent activity supposed to extend Fragmentactivity. Make sure LecturerFragment is an activity not a fragment. Also you have to startactivity from intent ie just do like this: startActivity(intent_lecturer); instead of how you did it.

Comment: But LecturerFragment must be a fragment. I have my reason to do it.